# Multidex in IntelliJ IDEA with Maven

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I've got a Maven project which currently is not an IntelliJ IDEA project. I imported it via File -> Open Project and then choosing the root pom.xml.

Everything seems to be imported fine, all modules are there and the Android modules are configured correctly.

I then added a run configuration for the Android module I want to execute.

When building I get the following error:

```
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [at.demoproject] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
```

But multidex is already set up and working fine with android-maven-plugin. (When building directly in the command line with Maven) I suspect that IntelliJ isn't using android-maven-plugin, but how do i tell it to use multidex then? Also, converting the project to Gradle is no option currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself.

Instead of letting IntelliJ built it, you can use Maven. Just open the Run/Debug configuration and remove "Make" in the "Before launch" list. Then add "Run Maven Goal" and enter the goals to run, in my case "clean install".